# Don't make functions within loops Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, dom-events, event-listener

I get that there are possibly three hundred of these questions, and I understand why not to. If we were looping saying a regular for loop, each iteration we are creating an anonymous function expression which is using more memory. Instead we take the function outside of the loop thus giving it a name

**Anonymous Function Iteration Example**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('elementName');
for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++ )
{
  elements[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
    console.log(e);
  });
}
```

**Named Function Iteration Example**

```
function handleClickEvents(e) {
   console.log(e);
}

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('elementName');
for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++ )
{
  elements[i].addEventListener('click',handleClickEvents);
}
```

Problem here is trying to prove someone the logic of this, and to be honest my jsperfs are disproving me completely. Please see the test results for yourself **[here](http://jsperf.com/best-event-listener-practice)**

So is jsPerf just wrong in the calculations or is this just a myth busted completely? I see that by running the anonymous function as my `eventListener` function I gain speed compared to the ladder.

Can anyone enlighten me to what the deal is here and why if we gain more speed with the first example should I even bother with two more lines from the second version?

Comment: The compiler sees that it's the same function, and it reuses it. It essentially translates the first code into the second.

Comment: Better explanation of what you mean, not sure where you were getting at with that Barmar sorry

Comment: @ArunPJohny so like I said is this myth busted or what? Which would you prefer in all honesty. I prefer the second method for cleanliness and readability though I'm also about speed, dependability, and reliability

Comment: This intrigues me.  [jslint docs](https://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop) have a good explaination for it and a [performance test](http://jsperf.com/closure-vs-name-function-in-a-loop/2) that shows poor performance when creating closure

Comment: See that's what I say as well. Though all programmers know that speed is key especially for larger APIs and projects -_- so damn illogical

Comment: @CorySilva I would never use an IIFE inside a loop really like that, though the format they show that fixes it seems to look a lot like my code. Except I'm not returning a function.

Comment: He's not actually calling the function, just assigning it. [This benchmark](http://jsperf.com/closure-vs-name-function-in-a-loop/10) is more appropriate, but it also shows that the named function is more than twice as fast in Chrome.

Comment: I think the primary reason for "not to create functions inside loops" is the closure "problem". Each of those functions share the same "loop scope". So, if you access any loop variables inside the those functions, you will always get the last value of those variables. Not creating functions in loops prevents from falling into this pit.

Comment: @FelixKling But if the function needs to reference the loop variable, it can't be defined separately at all. So that comparison doesn't really apply.

Comment: @Barmar: You mean if you want to have access to the value of that specific iteration? You can have a function that creates and returns a function and simply call that function. My point was just that memory is usually not the reason why one should not create a function inside a loop (I'm just thinking about the [JSHint warning](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#loopfunc))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not worry about performance-- I hardly imagine you are adding millions of event listeners.

The second alternative (specifying a function reference) is superior in that the function, once defined, could potentially be used in other places. It requires fewer `});`, and so is less prone to typos. Perhaps more importantly, it is potentially more readable. Let's take the example of passing a function to `Array#filter`, to check that a filename is a jpg:

```
names.filter(function(name) { 
    return /\.jpg$/i.test(name);
});
```

vs.

```
function isJpeg(name) { return /\.jpg$/i.test(name); }

names.filter(isJpeg);
```

If you're chaining methods together, the benefits become more obvious:

```
names . filter(isJpeg) . map(makeThumbnail) . forEach(uploadJpg);
```

At the end of the day it doesn't really matter and boils down to personal preference, but the one thing that is clear is that performance concerns should not be what drives your decision, except in very specialized situations. A good general rule is to write very short, one-off functions in-line. With ES6 and arrow functions, more functions can be "very short" and be candidates for inlining.

By the way, even when writing the function in-line, it's often a good idea to give it a name:

```
names.filter(function isJpeg(name) {
```

That has a couple of benefits. First, it's a form of documentation/comment and helps people read your code. Second, most debuggers and stack traces will do a better job of reporting about the function. Most minifiers will remove the name so there's no production impact.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is flaw in your comparison. If you were to reverse the code. Putting the anonymous function later of the comparison. It will be slower. (http://jsperf.com/best-event-listener-practice/5). Later code will always be slower because there has been so many binding has done before.

Comment: OK so it matters in the perf which test this first. Thanks for that. Though the comparison of mine to jslint is extreme. Does it matter to add the prep code ie benchmark the function in jsperf